# How to pass headers in the upstream request from nginx proxy server?

Tags: nginx, http-headers, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have to set custom headers for outgoing request using nginx proxy, so basically I started with trying add_header and proxy_set_header directive in the conf file(snippet has been added), but in the outgoing request these headers were not being added using either of them. Please suggest me an approach to solve this problem.

```
   server {
        listen       8095;
        access_log  logs/host.access.log;
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://www.dummy-site.com/applications/1232;
            proxy_set_header Authorization "some_authorisation";
            proxy_set_header referer "referer";
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        }
   }
```

Comment: Your config seems ok to me, so I'm just checked it on my sandbox. All headers are passed to upstream. Maybe it is something else that strips headers from request? BTW, `proxy_pass_request_headers on;` is default settings and you can safely remove it from your config.

Comment: how have you checked upstream headers on your end?

Comment: I have a [PHP diagnostic script](https://pastebin.com/kWCVVmL4) for such purposes.